# Load Balancer Spillover

Tags: load-balancing

I want to be able to throttle incoming web requests but when a threshold is reached then I want to return a temporary redirect to a file on a CDN instead of passing the request to the backend.

I can use servers like nginx to do the throttling but not the spillover. Are there any load balancers or web servers which can do this?